# Prevent HTML form action from being displayed on browser, or redirect to another page after the action being executed

Tags: html, forms

Alright let's put it this way: How can I "redirect" a user to another page, "MyPage.php" after submitting a form that looks like this:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/APageICanNotEdit.php" method="POST">

<input type="submit" name="send" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Please note that, I don't have control over the URL provided in the action attribute. It's an external source. Which means, I cannot edit the "APageICanNotEdit.php" file.

Here is what I want:

- User will click on submit button (Labeled as Go)
- `action="http://www.example.com/APageICanNotEdit.php"` - this action
  must be performed, if possible, without displaying the contents of it.
- I want the user to reach "MyPage.php" safely after
  "APageICanNotEdit.php" is executed.
- I need a solution without changing the URL in action, cause that
  defeats the purpose.

Comment: An AJAX call is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

use an hidden parameter like

```
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="1" />
```

Your form will look like this:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/form-manager.php" method="POST">

</form>
```

Yout form manager will look like this:

```
 if ($_POST['action'] == "1")
       require_once('ThePHPFileIDoNotWantToBeLoadedOnBrowser.php");
```

Seeing your comment, you can do it with an AJAX call:

```
$(document).on('submit' , 'form[action="http://www.example.com/ThePHPFileIDoNotWantToBeLoadedOnBrowser.php"]' , function(e){

     var formData = $(this).serialize(); // if you need any of the vars

     $.ajax({
         url:'someOtherURL.php',
         type:'POST',
         datatype:'json',
         data: formData,
         success : function(data){
             for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                 console.log(data);

             }
         },
         error : function(s , i , error){
             console.log(error);
         }
     });

     return true; // keep normal behavior
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro, but it includes the "ThePHPFileIDoNotWantToBeLoadedOnBrowser.php" file in the form-manager.php page. Form action can't be changed, it must be "ThePHPFileIDoNotWantToBeLoadedOnBrowser.php". Need a technique to make that happen behind the scenes :(

Comment: With an AJAX call, it could be easy to do it, I updated my answer with a jQuery AJAX call. For information, form[action=...] is a little crazy, prefer something else if possible...